# SVG: What to use when

Tags: svg

I'm starting with SVG files in my websites and I'm really wondering when to use the SVG code or the SVG image.

When I save a file from Illustrator as SVG I have two options:

- I can save the image
- I can export to code.

I could use either.  But when do I use what?  Is is smarter to use the image in my website or do I use the code?

With all the current knowledge I have I should use the code because that is way lighter (kb's). Or should I use the image as a fall-back?

Comment: I think that posting such a question to https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ would be a better fit.

Comment: @potame: why do you believe this question is about graphic design? It is not.

Comment: @Jongware well it doesn't look like a programming question either way. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I did found some interesting answers: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/63187/svg-what-to-use-when/63209#63209

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make use of the capabilities of a vector graphic (scalability, accessable elements, css styling,...) than you should save the code, what essentially is the graphic.

I personally prefer to insert the code directly into the html, so I have all options for script access and css styling.

However that has some downsides: no image cache, removal of non unique ids (if there are multiple svg embeded), style attributes which prevent from styling with css.

I found SVG cleaner very useful to generate clean and useful svg-code after the creation of the image.

If you do not need all that stuff and just want to display the graphic the use of the `<img>`, or via css background is the way to go, since that enables the browser to cache everything and saves you from all the clean up huzzle.

If your vector graphic contains a lot of effects which have to be rasterized (some illustrator filters for instance), or embedded images, than the final svg might be larger than an pixel image, since the data is embedded as base64 encoded string what adds ~20% to the filesize.

So the use of an png or jpg might be the right choice in that case.

To sum it up: it depends on your needs and characteristics of the graphic.

I hope I could help...